# Fastest/One-liner way to remove duplicates (by key) in Ruby Array?

Tags: ruby, arrays, duplicates

What's the fastest/one-liner way to remove duplicates in an array of objects, based on a specific key:value, or a result returned from a method?

For instance, I have 20 XML Element nodes that are all the same name, but they have different "text" values, some of which are duplicates.  I would like to remove the duplicates by saying "if element.text == previous_element.text, remove it".  How do I do that in Ruby in the shortest amount of code?

I've seen how to do it for simple string/integer values, but not for objects.

Comment: See my answer for a modern take.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's the standard hashy way.  Note the use of `||=` operator, which is a more convenient (`a ||= b`) way to write `a = b unless a`.

```
array.inject({}) do |hash,item|
   hash[item.text]||=item
   hash 
end.values.inspect
```

You can do it in a single line either.

The script needs O(n) equality checks of `text` strings.  That's what's covered under O(n) when you see a hash.

Comment: Not exactly the fastest, as it runs in O(n^2) time. Then again it's not really important given how cheap CPU time is now.

Comment: @EmFi , accessing hash table doesn't take O(n) (we should iterate string `text`, but we'll have to do it anyway).  I've just posted an answer about this matter:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590405/distinguishing-extra-element-from-two-arrays/1590536#1590536

Comment: @Pavel Sorry, you're right. I got confused for a second into thinking that the added values call made it O(n^2). When it just makes it O(2n).

Comment: This answer is valid but outdated, see my answer.

Answer (score 10):

This does it all:

```
Hash[*a.map{|x| [x.text, x]}].values
```

**short? yep.**

(asterisk is optional; seems to be required for 1.8.6).

For example:

```
a = [Thing.new('a'), Thing.new('b'), Thing.new('c'), Thing.new('c')]
=> [#<Thing a>, #<Thing b>, #<Thing c>, #<Thing c>]

Hash[a.map{|x| [x.text, x]}].values
=> [#<Thing a>, #<Thing b>, #<Thing c>]
```

Boring part: here's the little test class I used:

```
class Thing
  attr_reader :text
  def initialize(text)
    @text = text
  end

  def inspect
    "#<Thing #{text}>"
  end
end
```

Comment: it's gone in the new, even shorter, simpler version :). However, saying `ary.map{|x| x.last}` and `ary.map(&:last)` are equivalent.

Comment: I have the following error:  in `[]': odd number of arguments for Hash (ArgumentError)

Comment: huh? what's your output for `a.map{|x| [x.text, x]}`? I double checked this and it seems ok...

Comment: running ruby 1.8.6; didn't rewrite `inspect` method; here's the output: http://pastebin.com/d42b3ce59.  It happens to be **one** array of arrays, and one is an odd integer.

Comment: I guess they made a change from 1.8.6 to 1.8.7. I don't have access to 1.8.6, but I believe that you can do `Hash[*a.map{|x| [x.text, x]}].values` instead.

Comment: I *can* do that, but then the results then lacks one item :(  Here's my code so you can get the whole picture: http://pastebin.com/m1594877c

Comment: This answer is valid but outdated, see my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`Array#uniq`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-uniq) with a block. In your case:

```
array.uniq(&:text) # => array with duplicated `text` removed
```

This was introduced in Ruby 1.9.2, so if using an earlier version, you can use [`backports`](https://github.com/marcandre/backports) with `require 'backports/1.9.2/array/uniq'`