# Given an array with multiple repeated entries, fnd one repeated entry O(N) time and constant space

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

We have been given an array of size N that contains integers in the range 0 to N-2, both inclusive.

The array can have multiple repeated entries. We need to find one of the duplicated entries in O(N) time and constant space.

I was thinking of taking the product and sum of all the entires in the array, and the product and sum of all the numbers in the range 0 to N-2.

Then, the difference of the sums and the division of the products would give us two equations. This approach would work if it were given that there are only two repeated entries, but since there can be more than two, I think my approach fails.

Any suggestions?

Edit: The array is immutable. I realize that this is an important piece of information and I apologize that I forgot to include this earlier.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a nice treatment. It passes through some easier problems before addressing this one.

http://aperiodic.net/phil/archives/Geekery/find-duplicate-elements.html

It contains a solution for when you can modify the input array, and another for when you can't.

Brief summary in case the link ever dies: the array indexes run from 0 .. N-1, and the array values run 0 .. N-2. Each array element can therefore be considered as an index (or "pointer") into the array itself: element `i` "points to" element `ra[i]`, `ra[i]` points to `ra[ra[i]]` and so on. By repeatedly following these pointers, me must eventually enter a cycle, because we certainly can't go forever without revisiting some node or other.

Now, the very last element, N-1, isn't pointed to by any other element. So if we start there and eventually enter a cycle, somewhere along the way there must be an element which can be reached from two different places: the route we took the first time, and the route which is part of the cycle. Something like this:

```
  N-1 -> a1 -> a2 -> a3
               ^       \
              /         v
            a6 <- a5 <- a4
```

In this case, a2 is reachable from two different places.

But a node which is reachable from two different places is precisely what we're looking for, a duplicate in the array (two different array elements containing the same value).

The question then is how to identify a2, and the answer is to use [Floyd's cycle-finding algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection). In particular it tells us the "start" of the loop in O(N) time and O(1) space.

Comment: I'm still not entirely sure what the elements being pointers to the array means. Could elaborate on that a bit more?

Comment: @efficiency: the value of each element is a number less than N, hence is an index into the array. So if ra[N-1] is 4, then the next place to look is ra[4], which might perhaps be 7, and so on.

Comment: That's what I suspected. Thanks once again.

Comment: What is the significance of starting from n-1 (last) element? Can't we start from 0 too and still hit the cycle?

Comment: @AsadIqbal: no. For example if element 0 points to itself, and nothing else points to it, then we'll find a cycle but we haven't found an element that's pointed to from two different places because that cycle has no "tail". Position N-1 is special (it's not pointed to), and this means whatever loop it leads us into must have a tail. Of course we could work around this, by starting again at 1 if 0 doesn't help us, but I figured might as well start at the place guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming we are allowed to change array in place swap each element as you go through the array with the element on that "position" (e.g. if current element is curr then swap it with a[curr]) but if a[curr] already has curr then you know curr is a duplicate.

```
a = array...
for i = 0; i < length(a); i++
  curr = a[i]
  if a[curr] == curr:
    return duplicate curr
  swap(a[i], a[curr])
  # Now a[curr] == curr and so if it happens again we know it is a duplicate.
```

This would be O(n) and constant space.

Comment: What happens when a[0] contains 0 before you enter the loop?

Comment: This is totally bogus. Let us say that element 0 has value 1 and element 1 has value 5 (which is the duplicate value). When you see that element 0 has value 1 you swap the value with element 1 so now element 1 has value 5 and element 1 has value 1. You then loop the loop and say "Hurrah - element 1 has value 1 - it must be the duplicate!". Wrong. And moreover you now never get to check the value 5 in element 0. If element 2 contains 0, then you merely swap the 0 and the 5 AFTER you check the 2 and then move on, still never checking the 5.

Answer (score 1):

Scan the array and add each element to a set. If the item already exists in the set - you have a dupe.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize a bit array of size N-2 with all entries to 0. Each index will represent all of your items in the range 0 to N-2.

Loop through your array and add items to your bitarray by setting `bitarray[number] == 1`. If element already contains a 1, then you've already added your element, return immediately.

If you get to the end of your array without finding a duplicate, return -1.

Comment: Strictly speaking, a bitarray does not require constant space but space in the order of O(N).

Comment: We cannot make another array as the solution needs to be constant in terms of space complexity.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by [this SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151318/array-homework-question) I think I would choose to first sort the array in-place using an algorithm which is O(n) (though not necessarily fast) found in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) (nice graphical sorting demos found in [here](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~harrison/Java/index.html)), and then loop through the resulting array to find where the next number is equal to the current number.

Comment: O(n) sorting algorithms are very special and require additional assumptions. Beside that, your approach is slower than O(n) anyway due to your additional loop.

Comment: Sorting in n will use the bitfield approach... which is not constant space. And if you already got that, no need to sort anyway.

Comment: @PartlyCloudy: *If* he can sort in O(n), then another loop with O(n) will leave it in O(n).

Comment: Sorry, my first comment is wrong. The worst case complexity is max( sorting, O(n)).

Comment: So-called sorting in O(n) is a "cheat" here, I think. You can do it in constant extra space with a binary radix sort, but that (or any other radix sort) takes time Theta(k * N), where k is number of bits in the integers. But `N-2` can't be greater than 2^k, since the values of the integers range up to N-2. So really, the time is Theta(N log N), it's just that the "Java" tag might make us assume that an integer is an `int`, and hence that N is bounded above by a constant. But if we assume that, complexity analysis is irrelevant: we can *bubble sort* 2^32 values in O(1).

Answer (score 0):

Try thinking with other data structures. Some data structures, like a HashSet, won't traverse the current elements when adding or searching which keeps your O(n).

```
HashSet hSet = new HashSet();

for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++){    
    if(hSet.contains(array[i])
       return array[i];
    else
       hSet.add(array[i]);
}
return -1;
```

although I'm not sure that this will satisfy your memory requirements, extraneon's previous post with the inplace sort with a second traverse might be more what you are looking for

Comment: Again, we cannot make another data structure because that would violate the constant space restriction.

Answer (score 0):

(sorry can't add comments yet ....)

@Blastfurnace
ah.. good catch that for loops needs a check first

```
if a[i] == i:
  continue  # Don't swap with yourself!
```

If array is immutable then you can just keep following elements i.e. skip until a[i] == i then from a[i] goto a[a[i]]. This will hit a loop and then we can use "how to detect loop in a linked list" solution (keep 2 pointers one moves at speed 1 other at 2 and when they both meet you know you have hit the cycle).

If we can change array and then return it unchanged then we can cheat :)
From i = 0, turn a[a[i]] into a negative integer if it is not already, if it is already negative then we know that element a[i] has been visited twice. Before returning turn back all negatives into positives (for 0 use MIN_INT)