# to find which number is repeated

Tags: c

in a array[10],there are numbers from 1 to 9 in the array and one of the number is repeated (repeated number is also between 1 and 9) how to find the repeated number without using the loop, and array can be transversed only once from top to bottom.

this is not homework, this was asked in interview

Comment: If you can't use a loop how can you traverse the array? Are you just supposed to copy/paste the same operation for each of the elements? That's just silly (and sounds like a bad homework assignment).

Comment: You tell not to use loop and also traverse the array once!!!

Comment: To traverse the array from top to bottom you have to use a loop

Comment: therefromhere and Chris Lutz@ its not a homework, this was a Question in my interview

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The shortest answer has to be based on Vladimir's answer. There is no for loop, however it is also not expandable to variable size arrays. It is:

```
int repeated_number = array[9]+array[8]+array[7]+array[6]+array[5]
                     +array[4]+array[3]+array[2]+array[1]+array[0]-45;
```

Sweet and simple, answers the question. I think, the problem is that all the people answering this question are to used to writing good sensible code that can handle variable situations, but this is a short simple question so deserves a short simple answer.

Answer (score 7):

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 9; i >= 0; --i)
    sum+=array[i];
int repeatedNumber = sum - 45; // 45 = 1+...+9
```

This solution does use loop, but your condition is controversial - traversing array implies that the loop is used

Comment: That's an interesting pseudocode syntax you've got there, but +1 for the algorithm.

Comment: Thanks for comments, edited a question to have a proper code (hope I got the "from top to bottom" part correctly)

Comment: I wondered why your for loop looked odd :) Stupid bloody question as if it matters which direction you go. Looks like they're testing for ability to read the question more than ability to write good code.

Comment: Agree :) Although reading requirements carefully is also very important and may be should be taught (sometimes I miss important details because of hastiness and inattentiveness, so I wish I followed that guideline myself)

Answer (score 3):

Make an array of 10 bools. Each bool represent whetether its respective number already occurred. If you find bool while writing a true, the number is repeated.

Comment: +1 this is faster (less array traversal time) but more space inefficient (an array of `bool` can theoretically be 10 bits, but will likely end up with some unfortunate padding).

Comment: I'm not sure how C compilers would handle this, but C++ compilers tend to pack series of bools into one byte. You will of course still need two full bytes tho.

Comment: You're referring to the `std::vector<bool>` optimization. In C (and C++) `sizeof(T)` cannot be less than `sizeof(char)`, necessitating that `bool a[10]` be 10 bytes. It's possible the standard allows a smart compiler to see that the array is never accessed via pointer and perform that optimization, but it's certainly not something you can bank on.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure it works with arrays, but it works with structs - struct with 8 consecutive bools will have a size of one byte (tried that with VS 2008 C++ compiler).

Comment: This is slower than Vladimir's answer as you have to test the bool on each loop. Also, why an array of bools? Are you serious? It's so sad how the art of bit flags, mapping, and masking has died out. Just use a bit mask and set the bit corresponding to each number found.

Answer (score 0):

The Solution I give is from CommanderZ but the only difference is that I was bored and I do not want to go study so instead I did the code.

```
int FindDuplicate(int index)
{
    static bool initialized = false;
    static bool Existance[10];
    if(!initialized)
    {
        for (int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
            Existance[i] = false;
        initialized = true;
    }

    if(index == -1)
        return 0;

    if(Array[index] == true)
        return index;
    else
        Array[index] = true;

    return FindDuplicate(index - 1); //edit-fix

}
```

Also See this thread which might be a bit similar : [Given an array with multiple repeated entries, fnd one repeated entry O(N) time and constant space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4234027/given-an-array-with-multiple-repeated-entries-fnd-one-repeated-entry-on-time-a)

And this one too : [Array Homework Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151318/array-homework-question)

Comment: you have 9 numbers in your examples, not 10

Comment: If the array index is not already set, you don't return anything. I think you want `return FindDuplicate(index - 1);`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm bored too. Here's a solution using recursion and Vladimirs subtraction trick:

```
int find_dupe(int* array, int len)
{
    static int sum = 0;
    sum += array[0];

    if(len == 1)
        return sum - 45;

    return find_dupe(array+1, len-1);
}

int main()
{
    int array[10] = { 9, 2, 5, 8, 6, 7, 1, 3, 4, 2 };

    printf("dupe: %i\n", find_dupe(array, 10));

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a boolean array to indicate whether a value exists or not.  Use `true` to indicate the number exists.

```
int main(void)
{
  const unsigned int array_values[10] = {1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
  bool               is_resident[10] = {false};
  bool               duplicate = false;
  unsigned int       index = 0;
  duplicate = duplicate || is_resident[array[index]];
  is_resident[array[index++]] = true;
  duplicate = duplicate || is_resident[array[index]];
  is_resident[array[index++]] = true;
  duplicate = duplicate || is_resident[array[index]];
  is_resident[array[index++]] = true;
  duplicate = duplicate || is_resident[array[index]];
  is_resident[array[index++]] = true;
  duplicate = duplicate || is_resident[array[index]];
  is_resident[array[index++]] = true;
  duplicate = duplicate || is_resident[array[index]];
  is_resident[array[index++]] = true;
  duplicate = duplicate || is_resident[array[index]];
  is_resident[array[index++]] = true;
  duplicate = duplicate || is_resident[array[index]];
  is_resident[array[index++]] = true;
  duplicate = duplicate || is_resident[array[index]];
  is_resident[array[index++]] = true;
  duplicate = duplicate || is_resident[array[index]];
  is_resident[array[index++]] = true;
  std::cout << "Duplicate found: " << (char *)(duplicate ? "true" : "false") << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

The above code is not tested and specialized for this question.  This code has no other purpose in life in is not generalized.

*Note:  No loops were used or harmed in this example.*
*"There is always a third alternative." -- Thomas Matthews*